# Pass float3 from Swift struct to metal shader

Tags: swift, floating-point, shader, scenekit, metal

Boiling the issue down to minimal code, I have a metal fragment shader that returns a colour:

```
constant float3 uSeaColor = float3(0.39216,0.4549,0.51373);

fragment float4 fragmentMain(constant Uniforms& uniforms [[buffer(2)]]){
    return float4(uSeaColor.rgb, 1);
}
```

This returns the colour I expected and works as intended. However, I'm trying to pass this colour (and other uniforms) from a swift struct with:

```
struct Uniforms {
  var overlayOpacity: Float = 1.0
  var gridAlpha:CGPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.5, y: 0.5)
  var uSeaColor = SCNVector3(0.39216,0.4549,0.51373)
}

var uniforms = Uniforms()
let data = NSData(bytes: &uniforms, length: MemoryLayout.size(ofValue: uniforms))
sphereNode.geometry?.firstMaterial?.setValue(data, forKey: "uniforms")
```

and in my shader, a matching struct:

```
struct Uniforms {
  float overlayOpacity;
  float2 girdAlpha;
  float3 uSeaColor;
}
```

The issue is when I swap from the constant to the struct uniform colour, the colour doesn't match at all. Using the comparisons from [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/scenekit/scnshadable), I've tried passing in a float3 (`import simd`) and `SCNVector3`.

How can I make sure the constant float3 I use in my shader will be represented the same way when I pass it in from Swift?

Comment: Is this for macOS or iOS? According to [the docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/scenekit/scnvector3), on macOS the components of `SCNVector3` are `CGFloat` which, for 64-bit (as all Metal apps must be), is `double`, not `float`. MSL doesn't support `double`. So, you can't use that. `float3` should work. You have to use `MemoryLayout.stride`, not `.size`, though.

Comment: I'm using iOS, no luck with suggestions. However, I did have other `float` and other types inside my struct too. When I pass in a single float3 the colour shows as intended. Can my struct not have mixed types in it?

Comment: So you're saying that the problem described in the post is solved? (i.e. it works for `float3`). You should update your question with an example of what doesn't work.

Comment: I usually declare my uniforms in a separate C header, which I include both in the `Shaders.metal` and my project's bridging header.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My struct had a variety of types in it, using what I had read from the table [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/scenekit/scnshadable) I was passing in my `float2` as a `CGPoint`. Changing the types to match exactly what they are in the metal shader fixed all my problems. Obvious in retrospect.

Comment: LPT: define convenience initializers for float2 from CGSize and CGPoint, and store only simd types anytime you start to approach shader land :)